# Set Item postition in ActionBar

Tags: android

I have this layout that add **1 or more items** into the ActionBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
           android:id="@+id/item_test"                
           android:showAsAction="always|withText"
           android:title="SearchIcon"/> 
</menu>
```

And then I will add another item dynamically into the ActionBar from another Fragment or Activity

```
MenuItem populateItem = menu.add("My New Item - Reload Icon");
```

But I want the item that I just added to **stay in front** of the items I had before, like the picture:

[image]

If I add it like I did, the icons will be shown as the last picture, how can I get the alignment like in the second picture?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can re-order the menu items with the android:orderInCategory attribute in each  you need to move.
You have to play around with that option alogn with menuCategory.

For example, assign to all items:

```
android:menuCategory="system"
```

Then, just set lower orderInCategory values to the Items you want to keep on the left.

Order in category determines the order appearance, from low to high.

Comment: thanks! Its working correctly! lol took me longer to write, than getting an answer :P

Comment: Great! I had the same issue a week ago.

Comment: Thanks for this. Any way to do this dynamically, at runtime?

Comment: But if i am adding menu items dynamically, then how would i do it @chinaski?

Comment: @Diffy: menu.add(Menu.CATEGORY_SYSTEM, 1, 1, getString(...))

Comment: Setting orderInCategory seems to work even if you have not defined any category and have not set menuCategory.