# Action Overflow is not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have tried everything that i could have. gone through 6-7 articles except `http://developer.android.com/` and things totally messed up i don't know what i am missing or taking the reference of wrong articles.

Here is my code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


<item
    android:id="@+id/userIcon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_user"
    android:title="@string/app_name"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/listIcon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_list"
    android:title="@string/app_name"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_red"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/get_back"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_green"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/get_login"/>
</menu>
```

Activity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_product_list, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.listIcon:
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Menu list",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        break;
    case R.id.userIcon:
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "User Icon",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
    //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    return true;
}
```

#### Thanks a lot

Comment: @chintankhetiya its not giving any error or exception only not displaying last two items. after clicking on list_icon

Comment: Could you please tell me in what order you want the  icons to be appear? @rup35h

Comment: first two will be display and rest of them when i will click on second icon. @Emender

Comment: Feel free to explain what "is not working" means, exactly.

Comment: @laalto only one icon is displaying rest of them is not displaying in action bar

Answer (score 0):

Order in category determines the order appearance, from low to high check this link -> [Set Item postition in ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626383/set-item-postition-in-actionbar) try the following code, but i'm not sure about in which order you want the menus to appear

```
<item
android:id="@+id/userIcon"
android:orderInCategory="1"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:menuCategory="system"
android:icon="@drawable/icon_user"
android:title="@string/app_name"/>

<item
android:id="@+id/listIcon"
android:orderInCategory="2"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:menuCategory="system"
android:icon="@drawable/icon_list"
android:title="@string/app_name"/>

<item
android:id="@+id/menu_red"
android:orderInCategory="99"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
android:title="@string/get_back"/>

<item
android:id="@+id/menu_green"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
android:title="@string/get_login"/>
```

Comment: I got my answer after doing a lot search. Anyway thanks @Emender

Comment: So @rup35h , what was the problem ?!  Please tell.

Comment: @JoeBlow please have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328232/android-menu-option-not-appearing-in-android-4-4/21328362#21328362

Comment: @rup35h - thanks for the quick response!  You know, I'm only on brand-new phones, so they should definitely show it. Indeed, note that the Open (physical) button also does NOT work. Sucks!  Cheers ...

Comment: @JoeBlow whick phone are you using ?

Comment: Hi @rup35h .. I have a big selection of samsung, otc, moto., etc.  I may have found the answer. It looks like surprisingly if **you do load the two libraries**, on 4.1+ only, it makes it not work.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23721321/294884

Comment: Yup, there's the solution!  Note image ... stackoverflow.com/a/23721321/294884