# Android Menu option not appearing in Android 4.4

Tags: android

I have a options menu in my application which I have tested to work on Android 4.0.
The code is as shown below:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
     * Identify single menu item by it's id
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {

        case R.id.menu_share:

             //code to do something when chosen etc


            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Now if I run the same code on Android 4.4 (I tested on Moto G), the options menu is not appearing.

Any idea what I must do since there is no Android menu button on the device?

Comment: Paste ur Menu XML here @aandroidtest

Comment: If you're using Android 4 and above, there should be `ActionBar` that provides you with `overflow` menu button if the device doesn't have hardware menu button...

Comment: If that is for fragment then you must call setHasOptionsMenu(true)

Comment: Looking from the method signature, I guess he doesn't use `Fragment` though...

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your activity class if you want to Force to the Application to show the Action Overflow:

```
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
                .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
    }
```

#### Read This  http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html

#### The action overflow in the action bar provides access to your app's less frequently used actions. The overflow icon only appears on phones that have no menu hardware keys. Phones with menu keys display the action overflow when the user presses the key.

Comment: actually since KitKat - from hat I have read it is always visible: http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/12/09/google-engineer-unifies-the-menu-and-overflow-buttons-in-kitkat-makes-monty-python-jokes/. But I have no such device, so I am not 100% sure about it.

Answer (score -1):

Good practice is to call through to the super class:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

The reason you're not seeing the menu is probably that the device has a hardware menu button and that must be pressed to show the options menu.

Are you using the emulator? What is the setup for that?

Comment: No, I am using Moto G and there is no hardware menu button in the device.